# Using std::tuple correctly?

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

I recently learned how to use std::tuple (I had never needed it before then), and was curious as to when it is the proper time to use it over a container? I only ask because std::tuple doesnt feel like a container, since it requires things such as std::get and std::make_tuple.

Comment: When you need more than a [a pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) of values, I presume. You can also look at [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) as a kind of anonymous structure.

Comment: yes thank you. i actually forgot about std::pair so i should probably change it, since its only two objects

Comment: Related: One of my more frequently used cases for tuples, [lexicographical comparison logic using `std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie). Note specifically the example in the linked document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::tuple`s contain a fixed number of elements of varying types. You use it when you want to group together a few objects of different types. I would use it over a `struct` when the grouping doesn't have any particularly useful semantics. For example, a `std::tuple` is useful when a function needs to return multiple objects. A container, on the other hand, contains multiple elements of the same type (perhaps a varying amount).

Answer (score 8):

It's more of a replacement for a struct than for a container. However, in most cases you are better off actually defining a struct for readability reasons. Tuples are best used in templates with variable number of arguments.